# error when connect to singlestore through django

Tags: python, django, singlestore

I want to connect to singlestore through django with the following config:

```
DATABASES = {

     'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',

        'HOST': 'HOST',
        'NAME': 'NAME',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : '********',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
         'charset': 'utf8mb4',      
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1193, "1193 (HY000): Unknown system
> variable 'default_storage_engine'", 'HY000')

**django version is 4.7.2 and singlestore 6.8**

what can I do?

Comment: update your database it is EOL  and will not work with django 4.7.2

Comment: singlestore may be compatible with mysql's communication protocol and sql syntax, but will not necessarily support all of mysql's configurations. Django or mysql driver is clearly trying to set an option that is not valid for singlestore. If this behaviour is configurable in djago models or in the mysql driver, then remove the option. If not, then yo cannot use singlestore with mysql driver from django.